Push API without Notification API
I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). But this same issue occurs in FirebaseJS.
I want to use ONLY Push API to do in-browser messages without requiring ANY Notifications  API at all. In order to getToken() on Messaging, it seems like it also requires Notifications API support. I want to get a token to use for Push API, but have no need for Notification API support. Is this even possible?
When I call getToken() on Message in a service worker context, it always responds with an error pertaining to Notifications. Again, I don't want Notification API support.  Just Push Messages API.
The code I use is pretty basic:
getToken(fbMessaging, { vapidKey: '..' })

the error this like produces is:
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Notification". <--- I don't want to even try to use Notification API.
Note 1: Any call to getToken() inherently calls requestPermission(). Meaning, I don't have to call it separately.
Note 2: Generally, I only get this error on browsers that don't support Notification API.  But that's sort of the point/problem. I don't want to require Notification API support.
Note 3: These are definitely different APIs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification


I see you also commented on my answer to this previous question, which seems relevant (if not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778495/firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-gettoken-without-requesting-browser-permission/63778978?noredirect=1#comment138145897_63778978

@FrankvanPuffelen I agree - I think they're similar. But I felt the question you answered was focused around requestPermissions, and when/if you had to call it, or in what order. Mine is more focused on if its possible to call getToken() without needing Notification API support. I also felt like your answer focused around "quiet permission", when I'm not sure I'd even call for Notification permission checking at all - quiet or not.

Currently (April 2024) the Push API is made only for visible notifications.
You are asking about silent push, which has been requested by many people over the years, but it was never allowed.
You need the permission for notifications and you also MUST display a notification when you receive a push message, otherwise you will get blocked by some browsers (e.g. Chrome displays a default notification to inform the user, while Apple revokes your push subscription directly!).

Is that true even if the web page is in the foreground? In this case, isn't it allowed to not display a notification?

The following page section suggests that not showing a notification is allowed if you first check that your web page has the focus: https://web.dev/articles/push-notifications-common-notification-patterns#the_exception_to_the_rule. Is this incorrect?
